# Replace batteries of 20 TV remote controls

Tags: power-supply, batteries, remote-control

For an artistic installation, I need to use 20 TV remote controls. So I would like to replace their batteries (1.5V * 2 = 3V) with a single power supply.

- How to connect the remotes controls? In series?
- How to calculate the power supply needed for these 20 remotes?

Comment: Do you need to use them in the same time? Wouldn't be easier to use Samsung IR blaster? http://www.samsung.com/au/support/tv-audio-video/i-want-to-know-more-about-ir-blaster/

Comment: No, you would not wire them in series. You'd wire them in parallel.  You'd tie all the "positives" together and connect them to a 3V power supply's positive output. You'd tie all the "negatives" together and connect them to the same supply's negative (common, ground, etc.) output.  The supply would likely not need to supply more than a few hundred milliamps but that's just a guess.

Comment: Alright thank you mike65535. In series seems not working. Dorian, it's an artistical constraint I need to follow. But thanks for your advice.

Comment: @mike65535 it works !

Comment: @mike65535: Please use the answer box for answers and the comments section for clarification on the question.

Comment: I didn't have a current rating so I  didn't consider it a "answer".

Comment: Mods,  feel free to clean this up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you would not wire them in series. You'd wire them in parallel. You'd tie all the "positives" together and connect them to a 3V power supply's positive output. You'd tie all the "negatives" together and connect them to the same supply's negative (common, ground, etc.) output. The supply would likely not need to supply more than a few hundred milliamps but that's just a guess.